# Пиринговые торрент трекеры существуют?

Tags: p2p, torrent

Помню как 200 лет тому назад пользовался чем то похожим когда скачивал фильмы по локальной сети с помощью DC++.

Comment: трекер совершенно не обязателен. см. DHT

Comment: На сколько я помню то DC++ это для Direct Connect сетки (хабы и т.д.). Вымерло давно уже.